# How to write this operator in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to add the string `the color is green` inside the html based on the input I give in scss.

```css
@mixin jeansColor($jeancolor) {
  if(type-of($jeancolor)==string) {
    content: "the color is green"
  }
}

.jeans:after {
  @include jeansColor("green");
}
```

```html
<p class="jeans"> Jeans </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the little details...just forgot to instantiate the if with `@` : [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/NLvYvx) :)

```css
@mixin jeansColor($jeancolor) {
  @if(type-of($jeancolor)==string) {
    content: "the color is green"
  }
}

.jeans:after {
  @include jeansColor("green");
}
```

```html
<p class="jeans"> Jeans </p>
```